# Autohotkey Script to log into Gmail

Tags: gmail, autohotkey

I am trying to create a hotkey combination that opens up my browser and logs me into Gmail if I'm not already logged in. Does someone have a script for this?

Comment: Use Lastpass to keep you logged in anyway?!? The only reason I could think of wanting this is on a public machine and then you don't have AutoHotKey...

Comment: Oh and the script would have to contain your password, so if anyone else would get their hands on your .ahk script, you're screwed :-) However I like the idea of scripting these kind of things!

Comment: well keeping myself logged in all the time is unsafe as sometimes i have to leave my laptop unattended...but automating the login with a non-standard hotkey configuration (AHK) would prevent anyone besides me from accessing my account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a perfect solution, so anyone who feels like editing my answer go ahead.

But someone on [Just an asterisk](http://justanasterisk.com/autohotkey-command-line-gmail-ahk-script/) posted a AutoHotKey script to send a gmail from the command line.

I posted the script below and it requires your username and password in a seperate .txt file. On another site they gave the tip to put this file in an encrypted folder, so nobody can find out what your password is (unless you leave your computer unlocked).

```
;send gmail from the command line with CLgmail.exe by Just an Asterisk
filereadline, username, %A_ScriptDir%\logon.txt, 1
filereadline, password, %A_ScriptDir%\logon.txt, 2
server = smtp.gmail.com
port = 587
Gui, Add, Edit, vRec x6 y7 w420 h20, To?
Gui, Add, Edit, vSubject x6 y37 w420 h20,
Gui, Add, Edit, r9 vBodyText x6 y67 w420 h250, Message
Gui, Add, Button, x6 y327 w200 h20 gSendMail default, Send
Gui, Add, Button, x226 y327 w200 h20 gGUIhide, Cancel

^`::
    Gui, Show, x131 y91 h357 w435, Send a quick note
Return

SendMail:
    gui, Submit 
    string =  %username%_%password%_%server%_%port%_%rec%_%subject%_%bodytext%
    Run %A_ScriptDir%\CLgmail.exe %string%, ,Min
Return

GUIhide:
    Gui, Hide
Return
```

Now I need someone who can actually code to alter the script from launching a command line, to launching the browser and filling in the blanks there! Hope this helps you a bit.

Edit: I also found a little script/program someone created, but it's not made for AutoHotKey. Check it out [on Govermentsecurity.org](http://www.governmentsecurity.org/forum/index.php?showtopic=14088)

It uses to fill in the forms.

```
 'this will parse the form and add your inputs
 � 
 � web.document.Forms(0).email.Value = "" + Text2.Text
 � web.document.Forms(0).passwd.Value = "" + Text3.Text
 � web.document.Forms(0).submit
End Sub
```